# Argument of type 'take: 10' is not assignable to parameter type 'number'

Tags: c#, angular

{take: 10} --> this got error and show red underline

```
 getPendingCount(): void {
    if (!this.storageService.accessToken)
        return;
    this.prescriptionService.getPrescriptionStatusList({ take: 10 }, { skip: 0 }, { status: 1 })
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            const count = (data.length == 10) ? "9+" : data.length.toString();
            this.allMenus.find(menu => menu.name == 'Prescription').unreadCount = count;
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the method getPrescriptionStatusList. Is take variable int?

Comment: thanks for reply, i know what i missed up already...thanks a lot...